# How to avoid ' while counting words?

Tags: java, eclipse, maps

I've been given a task at school that requests to count words.
When I count words that are at the beginning of a quote, for example : 'she is smart' so the code counts the word " **'she** " like it's a different word from "**she**".

the code:

```
public WordsCount(String input){
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File(input));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sc.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z']+");
```

P.S. : 
If I want to count "she" and "she's" as different words

Comment: `[^A-Za-z']` would mean everything that is _not_ a character (upper and lower case) or an apostrophe (`'`). I'd guess you want to remove that apostrophe from that class - or do you want to treat "she's" etc. as a single word?

Comment: she and she's are different words. but she and 'she are the same for me

Comment: In that case I'd probably not use a regex for the delimiter but use a pattern to match words in the input (by line or the entire file), i.e. using the classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`. The regex would then need to match any sequence of characters and apostrophes in between, e.g. something like `(?i)[a-z]+('[a-z]+)?` - that `(?i)` makes the expression case insensitive so that `a-z` also matches upper case characters. `('[a-z]+)?` would match an optional sequence of an apostrophe followed by at least one more character.